# Why is $\sigma(X) = \{ X^{-1}(B) \ |\text{$B$ borel set} \}$ when $X$ is measrable if $X^{-1}(U) |\text{U open set}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I am following a book on probability theory. it says $X$ is a random variable if $X^{-1}(U)$ is in the sigma algebra for all open sets $U$. But on the other hand $\sigma(X) = \{ X^{-1}(B) \ |\text{$B$ borel set} \}$ is the smallest sigma algebra to which $X$ is measurable. Why do we not define it $\sigma(X) = \{ X^{-1}(B) \ |\text{$U$ open set} \}$ instead?

Comment: It turns out that they are the same, though this requires proof. The main point is an abstract set-theoretic observation: if $\Sigma$ if a $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{P}(B)$ and for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$ you have $f^{-1}(A) \in \Sigma$, then for every $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ you also have $f^{-1}(A) \in \Sigma$.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment is wrong; I got confused because you used the notation $\sigma(\cdot)$ differently from the standard. Let me clean it up. $\sigma(X)$ is defined *abstractly* as the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras with respect to which $X$ is measurable. By definition, this means that $X^{-1}(U) \in \sigma(X)$ for all open sets $U$. It is a *theorem* that then $\sigma(X)=\{ X^{-1}(B) : B \text{ is Borel } \}$. The main point of the proof of this theorem is the abstract set-theoretic observation from my previous comment.

Comment: Just to clarify further, $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing all elements of $\mathcal{A}$. This is related to but not quite the same as the $\sigma$ in $\sigma(X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast with $\sigma(X)$ the collection $\{X^{-1}(U)\mid U\text{ open set }\}$ is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra, so it would be wrong to identify the first collection with the second.

It can be proved though that $\sigma( \{X^{-1}(U)\mid U\text{ open set }\})=\{X^{-1}(B)\mid B\text{ borel set }\}$.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the identity map $\textrm{id} \colon \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ is a random variable on $\mathbf{R}$. The two sets
\begin{align}
\sigma(\mathrm{id}) = \{ \mathrm{id}^{-1}(B) \mid B \colon \text{Borel} \}
= \{ B \mid B \colon \text{Borel} \}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\sigma'(\mathrm{id}) = \{ \mathrm{id}^{-1}(U) \mid U \colon \text{open} \}
= \{ U \mid U \colon \text{open} \}
\end{align}
are different because $\{0\} \in \sigma(\mathrm{id})$ and $\{0\} \notin \sigma'(\mathrm{id})$. Furthermore, $\sigma'(\mathrm{id})$ is not a sigma algebra.

Comment: This technically answers the question but I think it misses the point, which is that it is perfectly fine to define $\sigma(X)=\sigma(\{ X^{-1}(U) : U \text{ open } \})$.